# High level rest client get only hits' size

Tags: java, elasticsearch

i know with transport client can get hits' count like this:

```
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchType;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders.*;

SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("your_index_goes_here")
.setTypes("YourTypeGoesHere")
.setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("some_field", "some_value"))
.setSize(0) // Don't return any documents, we don't need them.
.get();

SearchHits hits = response.getHits();
long hitsCount = hits.getTotalHits();
```

but how can i get hits' size with high level rest client?

Comment: `hitsCount` is the number of documents that match your query, what do you mean by "hits' size"?

Comment: sorry for my pool english, what i meant is hitsCount

Comment: You have `hitsCount` on the last line, not sure what else do you need?

Comment: yeah, there is hitsCount on the lastline, but the hits will also return with the count, which is superfluous. what i want is getting only hitsCount

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see what you're after. In your response, the hits array will be empty (since size=0) but hitsCount will contain how many documents match. Not sure what else is missing for you.

Comment: @soputasmile instead of using GET requests which gives you the entire body of hits, use HEAD requests which will only return the hitcount and no response body.

Comment: @Val what i meant is get hitsCount only but do not get hits

Comment: @koksalb thanks for your answer, but how can i use get request with java api in elasticsearch6.x ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Elasticsearch 6.6 or newer. Maybe you want to use the Count API: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/search-count.html

In high level rest client (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.6/java-rest-high-count.html):

```
CountRequest countRequest = new CountRequest("your_index_goes_here");
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.termQuery("some_field", "some_value"));
countRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);

CountResponse countResponse = client.count(countRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
long hitsCount = countResponse.getCount();
```

Comment: if count of all documents ( without any field), then omit
countRequest.source(..)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version with the REST client:

```
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder()
   .query(queryBuilder)
   .size(1);
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("your_index_goes_here");
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
SearchResponse response = highLevelClient.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
System.out.println("Total: " + response.getResponse().getHits().totalHits);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the response gets hitsCount through hits, the hits is useless for me, i only want to get hitsCount, is there a way to get hitCount only？

Comment: I don't think there is other API method for the same thing. It would be confusing why there are more than one methods for the same property of the result. Why do you need to avoid using `hits` ?

Answer (score 0):

Another potential solution is to use the aggregation builder and get the count that way.

```
sourceBuilder.aggregation(AggregationBuilders.count("totalCount").field("id"));
```

As you can see you can base it on the ID or any other unique value that would give you a total count of all fields based on the query you send.